# cron job as a different user?

Tags: php, cron

I need to call a script via curl in one of my cron jobs. The script needs write access to the web root. Apache doesn't have write access to my web root. How can I execute the cron job as a different user? Thanks.

Comment: What about a second cronJob(as a root) that collect the files that you want? Insecure, but maybe can fit to your needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use group permissions.

Create a group that will have write access to that directory.

```
groupadd web
```

Add yourself and apache to the new web group

```
useradd -G apache web
```

Change the document root's ownership permissions to belong to the new web group

```
chown -R you:web /path/to/docroot
```

Set the docroot writable

```
chmod a+w /path/to/docroot
```

Answer (score 0):

No matter how you go about this, you need an account (the more restricted, the better) that has write access to the web root.  This seems obvious, I know.  Next, log in as that user and create the cron job.  If you have root:

```
$ su
# su -u thisotheruser
$ crontab -e
```

and create the cron job.  A couple exits later, and you're all set.